# Ubuntu, Flash works on sites, not in localhost

Tags: html, flash, ubuntu, plugins

Ok, I'm working on making a webpage that is accessed through localhost on Ubuntu Firefox. I have one page (lps.html) that uses:

```
<embed width:"420" height="345"
src="http//www.youtube.com/watch?v-vbf1-euocAo">
</embed>
```

The problem is that when I load the page in Firefox as: localhost/lps.html the video player comes up saying:

"A plugin is needed to display this content"

I check Youtube itself and I can watch videos no problem, just not on my page.

I've been working at this problem for 6 hours and have become frustrated and decided to just ask the people here. Can someone please help me? I'm a beginner in Ubuntu and figure it's something stupid like assigning a directory for the page or adding something to localhost. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you **sure** you have Flash. Youtube can display videos in HTML5 format. Type `about:plugins` in your address bar and see if Shockwave Flash is listed.